# how to modify suavecontrols.materialforms in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget-package

I want to modify a entry made with the nugget package of this link https://github.com/SuavePirate/SuaveControls.MaterialFormControls

The declaration in xaml looks like this

```
<suave:MaterialEntry x:Name="Contrasena" IsPassword="True" 
Placeholder="Password" Style="{StaticResource Entries}"/>
```

and I create and effect to remove the underline, I already checked with a normal entry so I know it works. The code with the effect looks like this

```
<suave:MaterialEntry x:Name="Contrasena" IsPassword="True" 
Placeholder="Password" Style="{StaticResource Entries}"/>
    <suave:MaterialEntry.Effects>
        <local:NoUnderline></local:NoUnderline>
    <suave:MaterialEntry.Effects>
</suave:MaterialEntry>
```

I want to know why don't work, I suppose is because of the namespace where are each one.

This is what I put in contentpage to use materialforms in the xaml

```
xmlns:suave="clr-namespace:SuaveControls.MaterialForms;Assembly=SuaveControls.MaterialForms"
```

This is what is in the top of the xaml project

```
<ContentPage xmlns="xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-
namespace:Proyecto" x:Class="Proyecto.Registro" BackgroundColor="
{StaticResource GrisClaro}" xmlns:suave="clr-namespace:SuaveControls.MaterialForms;assembly=SuaveControls.MaterialForms">
```

And the local effect is like this in the pcl

```
public class NoUnderline : RoutingEffect
{
    public NoUnderline() : base("EffectsSample.NoUnderline")
    {
    }
}
```

And like this in android

```
public class NoUnderline : PlatformEffect
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Control != null)
            {
                if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.PreviewSdkInt >= (int)Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                    Control.BackgroundTintList = Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.White);
                else
                {
                    Control.Background.SetColorFilter(Android.Graphics.Color.White, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot set property on attached control. Error: ", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the correction Paul

Comment: What's the `local` namespace definition? Is `NoUnderline` something that *you* wrote or is it a suavecontrols builtin?

Comment: It is something that I wrote

Comment: Could be helpful to show the code, then.

Comment: I updated the code, if you want to see, why do you think don't work?

Comment: Great. What struck me is that there are semicolons separating your XAML namespace definitions. This is not correct, but I don't think that this is your issue, since it would not build (if you use compiled XAML) or throw a runtime exception, hence I believe that they are not there in you actual code, right?

Comment: they are in the actual code, I used from an example that I got. Only separates the namespace from the assembly, but I don't really know why it is used that way, I only see that is used like that in a few examples. It compiles and the application runs, but it didn't apply the effect

Comment: Yeah, they separate the namespace from the assembly, but in the sample they separate the XML namespace definitions which is not correct.

Comment: I didn't saw that before, sorry for the misunderstanding, yes in my code those semicolons are not there

Comment: Then download the suave project, make your changes that you need to it, compile it and include the .dll into your xamarin project.

Comment: thank you csharpest, I will check it

Comment: It doesn't let me compile because is a class library, I know it can be changed to compile but I don't know if that affects my code